# What would it take for the Bering Strait to freeze (and form a land bridge)?

Tags: ice, polar-region

What would it take for the Bering Strait to freeze (and form a land bridge)?

With the strait being composed of salt water, it would take a longer time at colder temperatures for ice to form.  Still, that is a **LOT** of ice, considering the distance between Alaska and Russia is still 83 km or 52 mi at the shortest distance, and having ice form in only a road's width across that distance is impossible.

Comment: It *does* freeze in winter, every year or almost every year. This does not mean that vehicles can cross, only that ships cannot cross: a frozen sea is not at all a nice smooth surface. Occasionally, people can cross from Asia to America on ice. The first documented crossing over ice, with sleds pulled by dogs, was done by Max Gottschalk in 1913; but he was very strongly incentivized to attempt it, because the Russian police wanted him.

Comment: @AlexP The phrase "Occasionally, people can cross" is what the question is trying to get at.  Please see the updated version of the question.

Comment: A land bridge, as the name suggests, is made of *land*. Even if you froze the Bering Strait solid and walked across it, it wouldn't be a land bridge

Comment: You can't edit questions in way which invalidate existing answers, like you did. Edit rolled back

Comment: @L.Dutch The question may now match an answer. It even matches what was originally written.  But it does not match my original intent, as pointed out by people above.

Comment: We can't know what you think, we can only know and answer what you write. You should have checked better before posting.

Comment: @L.Dutch I tried to remedy that. Unfortunately, someone reverted all my edits.

Comment: Did you mean "ice bridge"?

Comment: @Wyck Yes, but I have received pushback when I tried to edit the question.

Answer (score 5):

The Bering Strait freezes every year, between March and May.

Well, almost every year...

https://adventureblog.net/2019/03/the-bering-strait-is-almost-completely-ice-free.html

What would it take to form a land bridge? Oddly, it would take an ice age. The ocean would need to drop by at least 50 feet, which isn't much of a stretch. Every 40k years, ice piles up on Siberia and Canada, reducing the amount of water in the oceans. Not only would this cover the area in ice, it would lower the oceans to where the ice was sitting on dry land.